# Javascript validation not working on submit

Tags: javascript

I programmed this to check my form data, however, it does not work. First I check all the values, if they are null, then I check if email adress is valid and then I check if the checkbox is checked.

When I submit the form with no values on input, it successfully loads the document specified in `action="#"`, which should not happen because of the `return false;`.

```
function validateForm() {
            var meno = document.forms["registracia"]["meno"].value;
            var priezvisko = document.forms["registracia"]["priezvisko"].value;
            var telefon = document.forms["registracia"]["telefon"].value;
            var email = document.forms["registracia"]["email"].value;
            var vek = document.forms["registracia"]["vek"].value;
            var praca = document.forms["registracia"]["praca"].value;
            var motto = document.forms["registracia"]["motto"].value;
            var osoba = document.forms["registracia"]["osoba"].value;

            if (meno == null || meno =="" || priezvisko == null || priezvisko =="" ||
            telefon == null || telefon =="" || email == null || email =="" ||
            vek == null || vek =="" || praca == null || praca =="" || 
            motto == null || motto =="" || osoba == null || osoba =="" ||) {
                alert("Musíte vyplniť všetky údaje.");
                return false;
            }
            var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            if(!re.test(email)) {
                alert("Zadajte platnú e-mailovú adresu.");
                return false;
            }

            if(!document.forms["registracia"]["suhlas"].checked) {
                alert("Musíte súhlasiť s uverejnením vašej fotografie.");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please specify "does not work".

Comment: Is it being ran at all? Is there a visible error being thrown? Come on! More details please :)

Comment: More Details plz : ) !

Comment: Post edited with more details.

Comment: Not enough details, could you confirm the script is being ran? Also have you checked browser console for errors?

Comment: @MichalKlouda how do I do that?

Comment: E.g. in Chrome press F12 and click Console. To check that the validation script runs you can add an alert to first line.

Answer (score 1):

You had an extra `||` at the end of your `if` condition. You can also make it a bit more readable, see below.

```
function validateForm() {
    var form = document.forms["registracia"];

    if ( !form.meno.value 
            || !form.priezvisko.value 
            || !form.telefon.value 
            || !form.email.value 
            || !form.vek.value 
            || !form.praca.value
            || !form.motto.value
            || !form.osoba.value ) {
        alert("Musíte vyplniť všetky údaje.");
        return false;
    }
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if(!re.test(form.email.value)) {
        alert("Zadajte platnú e-mailovú adresu.");
        return false;
    }

    if( !form.suhlas.checked ) {
        alert("Musíte súhlasiť s uverejnením vašej fotografie.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now :). I really make lots of stupid mistakes.

Comment: Nah, mistakes are never stupid. The only stupid thing would be not learning from them